Can't import KerassRegressor
I have been trying to import KerasRegressor hyper-parameterization of the LSTM time series model to improve its performance in both HPC Linux** and **Windows. For this, I installed tensorflow using pip and tried to import KerasRegressor as follows without success.

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.keras.wrappers'

Unfortunately, it displays Traceback as follows
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[67], line 1
1 from tensorflow.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.keras.wrappers'

Later, I learned that it had been migrated, so I tried the second option as follows:
`from scikeras.wrappers import KerasRegressor`
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[68], line 1
1 from scikeras.wrappers import KerasRegressor
File /path/to/conda_envoronment/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scikeras/wrappers.py:35
33 from scikeras.utils import loss_name, metric_name
34 from scikeras.utils.random_state import tensorflow_random_state
35 from scikeras.utils.transformers import ClassifierLabelEncoder, RegressorTargetEncoder
38 class BaseWrapper(BaseEstimator):
39     """Implementation of the scikit-learn classifier API for Keras.
40 
41     Below are a list of SciKeras specific parameters. For details on other parameters,
(...)
124         The number of features seen during `fit`.
125     """
File /project/swmru_apex/myspatial/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scikeras/utils/transformers.py:12
10 from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
11 from sklearn.exceptions import NotFittedError
12 from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
13 from sklearn.preprocessing import FunctionTransformer, OneHotEncoder, OrdinalEncoder
14 from sklearn.utils.multiclass import type_of_target
File /project/swmru_apex/myspatial/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py:19
16 import numpy as np
17 from scipy import sparse
19 from .base import TransformerMixin, _fit_context, clone
20 from .exceptions import NotFittedError
21 from .preprocessing import FunctionTransformer
ImportError: cannot import name '_fit_context' from 'sklearn.base' (/path/to/conda_environment/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/base.py)

I really appreciate is there any other ways to hyper parameterize the LSTM time series model if there is no solution to it. If so, how it could be implemented in k-fold cross validation as well. Sooner response is greatly appreciated.
Thanks
I am trying to hyper-parameterize deep learning model as well as cross validate.

I can't really help you further, but I would suggest you check what versions of the packages you have installed, there might be problematic mismatches there.

Hi @Mahesh Maskey , TheKerasRegressorclass has been moved fromtensorflow.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn to scikeras.wrappers. However, the error message suggests there might be a version conflict or compatibility issue with the scikeras package.
Regarding scikeras.wrappers, the error indicates a compatibility issue with scikit-learn. This often occurs when there is a version mismatch between scikeras and scikit-learn.Ensure you have the latest versions of tensorflow, scikit-learn, and scikeras installed
